# Can't upload files above 1mb in Dropzone

Tags: javascript, symfony, dropzone.js

I used [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com) to handle the file uploads in my Symfony2 project.

It's working fine if I upload files below 1mb but when I upload a file exceeding 1mb, it throws an exception.

I thought the problem was on the `maxFilesize` config of Dropzone but it wasn't.  It was working since it shows a message that the file size exceeds the max size that I've set.

My form:

```
<form id="quickUpload" action="{{ path('upload_process') }}" method="put" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone">
   <div class="fallback">
       <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
   </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
Dropzone.options.quickUpload = {
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            dictDefaultMessage: "Drop files to upload (or click)",
            maxFilesize: 5,
            init: function () {
                this.on("success", function (file, response) {
                    file.serverId = response.id;
                });

                this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
                    if (!file.serverId) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var url = "{{ path("delete_upload") }}";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {id: file.serverId},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log("File Deleted");
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            console.log("File Delete Error");
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
 }
```

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/upload_process", name="upload_process")
 * @Method("PUT")
 */
public function uploadProcessAction(Request $request) {

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $files = $request->files;
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $ids = [];

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $document = new Document();
            $document->setUploader($this->getUser())
                    ->setFile($file);
            $em->persist($document);
            $ids[] = $document;
        }
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse(['id' => $ids[0]->getId()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the exception is... ? Have you tried to read its message?

Comment: Some SQL Exception. When I hover my cursor on the file it shows this message:

An exception occurred while executing INSERT INTO Document (name, type, description, extension, dateUploaded, path, uploader_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

It seems that it's been inserting null values into the database.

Comment: So why are those values null?

Comment: I don't know why it does that.  That doesn't happen when I upload files below 1mb.

Comment: So debug it. It's a community for developers.

Comment: Finally fixed it. Turns out the I just needed to modify the value of upload_max_filesize in my php.ini file to my desired maximum file size.

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed it.  I just needed to change the value of the `upload_max_filesize` in my `php.ini` file.  I saved the file, restarted XAMPP and got it working.